# prove that $\frac{b+c}{a^2}+\frac{c+a}{b^2}+\frac{a+b}{c^2}\ge\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$

Tags: inequality

Assume: $a,b,c >0$ prove that :

$$\frac{b+c}{a^2}+\frac{c+a}{b^2}+\frac{a+b}{c^2}\ge\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Since you are new, I want to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many users find the use of the imperative ("Find", "Show", etc) to be rude when asking for help. Please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: How is $x,y,z$ related to $a,b,c$?

Comment: Thank you  Arturo Magidin,i found other problems were posted like this so i thought it is the right way.

 Marvis, i edited that .

Comment: Can we use  Tchebyshev's inequality here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace $(a,b,c)$ by $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ for notational convenience, and start with the inequality
$$
\sum_{i,j}(x_i-x_j)\cdot\left(\frac1{x_j^2}-\frac1{x_i^2}\right)\geqslant0,
$$
which holds because every term in the sum is nonnegative. Expanding the LHS, one gets
$$
\sum_{i,j}\frac{x_i}{x_j^2}\geqslant\sum_{i,j}\frac1{x_i}=3\cdot\sum_i\frac1{x_i}.
$$
Separating the terms such that $i=j$ from those such that $i\ne j$ in the LHS yields
$$
\sum_{i\ne j}\frac{x_i}{x_j^2}\geqslant\color{red}{2}\cdot\sum_i\frac1{x_i},
$$
which is strictly stronger than the inequality to prove thanks to the factor $\color{red}{2}$ in the RHS. 
Furthermore, this inequality is strict except when all the $x_i$s are equal. Finally, the same proof works for $n$ terms instead of $3$, yielding a factor $n-1$ instead of the factor $\color{red}{2}$.

Answer (score 6):

I assume that by $x,y,z$ you mean $a,b,c$.

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $c$ is the smallest of the three i.e. $a, b \geq c >0$. Then
\begin{align}
\dfrac{b+c}{a^2} + \dfrac{c+a}{b^2} + \dfrac{a+b}{c^2} - \dfrac1a - \dfrac1b - \dfrac1c & = \dfrac{b+c-a}{a^2} + \dfrac{c+a-b}{b^2} + \dfrac{a+b-c}{c^2}\\
& = \dfrac{b^3 +b^2c - ab^2 + a^2c + a^3 - a^2b}{a^2b^2} + \dfrac{a+b-c}{c^2}\\
& = \dfrac{c(a^2+b^2)+a^3+b^3-a^2b - ab^2}{a^2b^2} + \dfrac{a+b-c}{c^2}\\
& = \dfrac{c(a^2+b^2)+(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)-ab(a+b)}{a^2b^2} + \dfrac{a+b-c}{c^2}\\
& = \dfrac{c(a^2+b^2)+(a+b)(a^2-2ab+b^2)}{a^2b^2} + \dfrac{a+b-c}{c^2}\\
& = \dfrac{c(a^2+b^2)}{a^2b^2}+\dfrac{(a+b)(a-b)^2}{a^2b^2} + \dfrac{a+b-c}{c^2}\\
\end{align}
Note that each term on the right side is non-negative. In fact, the first term (since $a,b,c >0)$ and last term (since $a,b \geq c > 0 \implies a+b > c$) are strictly positive. Hence, $$\dfrac{c(a^2+b^2)+(a+b)(a-b)^2}{a^2b^2} + \dfrac{a+b-c}{c^2} > 0$$ Hence, $$\dfrac{b+c}{a^2} + \dfrac{c+a}{b^2} + \dfrac{a+b}{c^2} - \dfrac1a - \dfrac1b - \dfrac1c > 0$$which gives us more than what we want.

Answer (score 3):

Using the AM-GM inequality we obtain:
$$\frac{b+c}{a^{2}}+\frac{c+a}{b^{2}}+\frac{a+b}{c^{2}}=\frac{b^{3}c^{2}+b^{2}c^{3}+a^{2}c^{3}+a^{3}c^{2}+a^{3}b^{2}+a^{2}b^{3}}{a^{2}b^{2}c^{2}}\ge2\frac{a^{3}bc+b^{3}ac+c^{3}ab}{a^{2}b^{2}c^{2}}=2\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}{abc}$$
Now a bit of juggling around proves an even stronger result:
$$2\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}{abc}=\frac{(a-b)^{2}+(a-c)^{2}+(b-c)^{2}+2(ab+bc+ac)}{abc}\ge2\frac{ab+bc+ac}{abc}=2\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)$$
In both estimates above equality is attained when $a=b=c$ which can be checked directly.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: One may start proving the inequality:

$$\frac{b+c}{a^2}+\frac{c+a}{b^2}+\frac{a+b}{c^2}\ge\ \frac{9}{a+b+c}+ \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$$

that is easy to prove. I met some time ago this inequality and have just remembered now. Of course, it's easy only if you met it before, otherwise it's rather hard to make such a guess.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{b+c}{a^2}-\frac{1}{a}\right)>\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{b+c}{a^2}-\frac{2}{a}\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{c-a-(a-b)}{a^2}=\sum_{cyc}(a-b)\left(\frac{1}{b^2}-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2(a+b)}{a^2b^2}\geq0$$
Done!